# What is fieldsObject in Event Tracking?

Tags: events, google-analytics, event-tracking

I am implementing the event tracking on my website so I understand the use of these "ga('send', 'event', [eventCategory], [eventAction], [eventLabel], [eventValue], [fieldsObject]);" but here what's the role of "fieldsObject"?

Can't understand. Share your knowledge in simple language as I read about it but it's hard to understand.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events i think its an optional field.  I will ping google and have the documentation looked at see if they cant make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

This optional field is used for additional parameters such as `nonInteraction: true` for example.